# Trying to filter data by nesting routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that lets users ask questions to be answered by professionals.  In addition to the question and answer model, the app keeps track of categories in the following way

```
Question.rb

 has_many :categorizations
 has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
```

Category.rb

```
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :questions, through: :categorizations
```

Categorization.rb

```
 belongs_to :question
 belongs_to :category
```

Right now, I can go to localhost:3000/categories and see a list of all the categories with questions in them. However, although categories are important, it's not very practical because due to the nature of the questions being asked, it's unlikely that someone in California would be able to answer a question asked about New York. Therefore, I'd like to have questions filtered by location as well. I'm guessing the best way to set up the URL would be like this

```
localhost:3000/state/ny/categories
```

which I understand I could do by creating nested routes (if, for example, I created a locations resource)

```
resources :states do
    resources :categories 
end
```

So, although I originally had the location stored as a field on Question model, I now created a Location model (in case 'State' is a reserved word, which I wasn't sure about). I did

```
Location.rb

has_many :questions

Question.rb

belongs_to :locations
```

and also did the nested routing so I could filter categories by states

```
  resources :locations do
        resources :categories 
  end
```

However, you'll notice that I didn't create an association between the location and the category, so if I go to this route

```
http://localhost:3000/locations/ny/categories
```

and if the index.html.erb view page shows how many questions exist for each category

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class="category">
    <h5><%= link_to category.name, category %></h5>
    <%= pluralize category.questions.size, "question" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

it's not being filtered by location. For example, it still counts all the questions regardless of location.  There's no benefit to having the routes like this unless I add some logic in the view that filters the location.

Instead of categories, I also tried nesting questions, but that doesn't change anything either obviously.

```
  resources :locations do
        resources :questions
  end
```

I think you can see what I'm trying to do. Can you suggest how I'm supposed to do it.

For example, should I be creating an association between location and category, and, if so, how would it work with that join model I have Categorization - can it belong_to three other models. Or how should I otherwise be filtering questions or questions that are listed in categories by location.

Thanks if you can provide some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you should use nested resources for routing when you have unique requirements. I would setup up routing like this

```
get locations/:state/categories => "categories#index"
get locations/categories => "categories#index"
```

Inside `categories#index` I would check `if params[:state].nil?` based on this you can decide whether to filter by state or not in your retrieval query and the view would remain the same

Answer (score 1):

The filtering doesn't happen automatically with the nested routes in place, you still have to do it manually. Nested routes are there to make things a bit easier to manage, as well as to enhance the experience for the user, not to do the heavy lifting for you. So in your case, in your view you'd need to change the code for getting the counts to something like the following:

```
category.questions.where(location_id: params[:location_id]).size
```

Where you're using the `:location_id` passed in through the URL to filter it. There are a couple of other issues here too though: for one, that sort of logic should really not be in a view, but possibly in your model instead; more seriously, by default rails needs to use the location's `:id` in the url, not it's name/abbreviation, so you'd need the route to be `/location/1/categories` rather than `/locations/ny/categories` (although there are gems that may allow you to get around this requirement).